# How to preselect a row in MUI data grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am trying to preselect a row in the MUI data grid and I am confused how to implement it. I am bringing in `preselectedContactName` as a prop which is used to filter the `contacts` array and find the exact `contact object`. Then after finding the correct one I am storing that to the state of `preSelectedContact`.

```
export const AccountContactsContent = (props) => {
  const { contacts = [], preselectedContactName } = props
  const [preselectedContact, setPreselectedContact] = useState('')
  const [preselectedRow, setPreselectedRow] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const contactToBeSelected = contacts.filter(
      (contact) => contact.name === preselectedContactName
    )
    setPreselectedContact(contactToBeSelected)
  }, [preselectedContactName])
```

This is where i get confused on how to use the `selectionModel` and `onSelectionModelChange` which I just added to the `DataGrid`. I want it to be where when the page loads, depending on the contact name clicked, it preselects the row containing the contact but still be able to click on other rows after. I created `preselectedRow` as another state to try and store the row being clicked but I am messing up somewhere with `selectionModel` and `onSelectionModelChange`

```
 <DataGrid
    autoHeight={true}
    className={styles.dataGrid}
    columns={columns}
    getRowClassName={({ row }) => (row.isDeleted ? styles.inactive : '')}
    getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
    hideFooterSelectedRowCount
    initialState={{
      pagination: { pageSize: 10 },
    }}
    keepNonExistentRowsSelected
    onRowClick={({ row }) => selectContact(row)}
    onSelectionModelChange={(preselectedContact) => {
      setPreselectedRow(preselectedContact)
    }}
    pageSize={10}
    rowCount={contacts.length}
    rowHeight={100}
    rows={contacts}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]}
    selectionModel={preselectedRow}
  />
```